# How to change image when cursor hover over the image in asp.net website

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btn_Send" runat="server" ImageUrl="Styles/Images/send_message.png"
                                    ValidationGroup="SM" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="Send_Click" />
```

I have this button in my website, how can I change image when the user hover over the image or when the user clicks the image, I want to show the user the button is clicked. So I have created another image for send_message.png(1) which looks like clicked, so when user hover over of clicks the image I want to display send_message.png(2)

Comment: Thanks for the answers, How can I do the same when  a image is clicked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<asp:ImageButton id="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images\1.gif"
OnMouseOver="src='Images/2.gif';"
OnMouseOut="src='Images/1.gif';">
</asp:ImageButton>
```

Answer (score 8):

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btn_Send" runat="server" CssClass="myButton"
                                    ValidationGroup="SM" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="Send_Click" />
```

CSS

```
.myButton{
    background:url("Styles/Images/send_message.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
.myButton:hover{
    background:url("Styles/Images/send_message2.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

if you can make a one image with using both images, it will be more easier.

[image]

```
.myButton{
    background:url("Styles/Images/send_message.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
.myButton:hover{
     background-position:bottom;
}
```

To change image in `click` event, you can add this on your `buttonclick`

```
btn_Send.Attributes.Add("class", "some-class");
```

and in your `css`

```
.some-class{background:url("Styles/Images/send_message2.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent !important;}
```

Comment: +1 for simple and the best way. Also the best way is to use 1 image which contains both default and hover state (Image Splicing). This means that there is no additional image load when the user hovers over the image. The use of Javascript is a very old and outdated method for something like this, and there will be an additional image load when the user hovers over the button unless you then add in extra javascript to pre-load the image.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, How can I do the same when a image is clicked

Answer (score 2):

Use javascript on mouse over event.

See it [here](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/onmouseo.htm)!

Comment: the is something called css, what happen if browser with javascript disable?

Comment: ouch for suggesting a javascript option when simple html/css is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_Send" runat="server" ImageUrl="Styles/Images/send_message.png"    ValidationGroup="SM" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="Send_Click" onmouseover="this.src='button2.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='Styles/Images/send_message.png'"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following lines at page_load event in your code page.

```
Image1.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.src='originalPic.jpg'");
Image1.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.src='newPic.jpg'");
```